# join two tables based on first 3 chars of nvarchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this simple sql statement, but my problem is i need to ensure that the firstname in table one matches the firstname in table 2 this should be simple but when i do this it cuts my data down a lot, i want to try doing this by only matching the first 3 chars of the first name to see if that helps

i was thinking to do this in the join section but i am not sure how to do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      TOP (100) PERCENT database.dbo.NAMES.SRNAME, SUM(dbo.claim.[TOTAL PAID AMOUNT]) AS TOTAL, YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                      - YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, CAST(database.dbo.NAMES.BORN - 2 AS int))) AS AGE1, dbo.claim.[BOOKING #], CONVERT(datetime, 
                      CAST(database.dbo.NAMES.BORN - 2 AS int)) AS DOB, dbo.claim.[PREMIUM YEAR]
FROM         database.dbo.NAMES INNER JOIN
                      dbo.claim ON database.dbo.NAMES.BOOKNO = dbo.claim.[BOOKING #] AND 
                      database.dbo.NAMES.FIRST = dbo.claim.[FIRST NAME]
WHERE     (dbo.claim.[PLAN #] = 'F432C' OR
                      dbo.claim.[PLAN #] = '00000F432C') AND (isnumeric(dbo.claim.[BOOKING #]) = 1)
GROUP BY database.dbo.NAMES.SRNAME, database.dbo.NAMES.BORN, dbo.claim.[BOOKING #], dbo.claim.[PREMIUM YEAR]
ORDER BY dbo.claim.[BOOKING #]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join t1 to t2 on LEFT(t1.fname, 3) = LEFT(t2.fname, 3)
```